# Can't install Open-CV on RasberryPi Python

Tags: python, opencv

My RasberryPi is V4
Python Version: 3.9.5

First Error code
This occurred after trying to install the module with apt command

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/surveillance-app/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Current error code
This happened when I installed the module with the command below

```
pip install --no-use-pep517 opencv-python


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/surveillance-app/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libIlmImf-2_5.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What I have tried

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
pip install opencv-python
pip install --no-use-pep517 opencv-python

#I tried the command below at first to install all the necessary modules and there was no error. 
sudo apt install -y \
    automake \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    libatlas3-base \
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
    python3-opencv
```

Source code

```
# Copyright 2021 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this
# software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software
# without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify,
# merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
# permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED,
# INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A
# PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
# HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
# OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
# SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
#

import datetime
import os
import subprocess
import time

import boto3
import cv2
import dlib

KVS_STREAM_NAME = os.environ["KVS_STREAM_NAME"]
SNS_TOPIC_ARN = os.environ["SNS_TOPIC_ARN"]

KVS_PRODUCER_BUILD_PATH = os.environ["KVS_PRODUCER_BUILD_PATH"]
APP_NAME = "kvs_gstreamer_sample"

# 顔検出時に録画を行う秒数
RECORD_SEC = 30
# HLSでのセッションの有効期限(分)
EXPIRATION_MIN = 60
EXPIRATION_SEC = 60 * EXPIRATION_MIN


kvs = boto3.client("kinesisvideo")
sns = boto3.client("sns")

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()


def detect_face():
    """ Wait until faces detected using Dlib """
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        _, frame = camera.read()
        frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results, _, _ = detector.run(frame_rgb, 0)
        if results:
            break
    camera.release()
    return


def upload_video():
    """ Upload video using Amazon Kinesis Video Streams Producer SDK C++ """
    start = time.time()
    kvs_app = f"{KVS_PRODUCER_BUILD_PATH}/{APP_NAME}"
    try:
        subprocess.run(
            [kvs_app, KVS_STREAM_NAME],
            cwd=KVS_PRODUCER_BUILD_PATH,
            timeout=RECORD_SEC
        )
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        end = time.time()
        print("record finished")
        return start, end
    print("record interrupted")
    return None, None


def get_session_url(start, end):
    """ Get HLS streaming session URL """
    endpoint = kvs.get_data_endpoint(
        APIName="GET_HLS_STREAMING_SESSION_URL",
        StreamName=KVS_STREAM_NAME
    )['DataEndpoint']

    kvam = boto3.client("kinesis-video-archived-media", endpoint_url=endpoint)
    url = kvam.get_hls_streaming_session_url(
        StreamName=KVS_STREAM_NAME,
        PlaybackMode="ON_DEMAND",
        ContainerFormat="MPEG_TS",
        DisplayFragmentTimestamp="ALWAYS",
        Expires=EXPIRATION_SEC,
        HLSFragmentSelector={
            "FragmentSelectorType": "PRODUCER_TIMESTAMP",
            "TimestampRange": {
                "StartTimestamp": start,
                "EndTimestamp": end,
            }
        },
    )['HLSStreamingSessionURL']
    print(f"HLS session URL: {url}")
    return url


def notify_url(url, timestamp):
    """ Notify HLS streaming session URL via Amazon SNS """
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    subject = "通知: 顔を検出しました"
    message = f"""セキュリティカメラで顔を検出しました。

ストリーム名: {KVS_STREAM_NAME}
日時: {date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')}
再生用URL: {url} ({EXPIRATION_MIN}分のみ有効です)
"""
    sns.publish(
        TopicArn=SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
        Message=message,
        Subject=subject
    )


def main():
    print("start surveillance application")
    while True:
        detect_face()
        print("face detected: start recording")
        start, end = upload_video()
        if start and end:
            url = get_session_url(start, end)
            notify_url(url, start)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have tried to find a way to solve this on the internet but I had no luck.
How can I solve this? If anyone could help me, I would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install openexr`

Comment: Did you mean to use `pip3` and not `pip`? `pip3 install opencv-python`

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ sudo apt install python3-opencv
$ python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
3.2.0
$ pip3 install opencv-python
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately it didn't work. 
When I tried "python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
3.2.0" this error occurred. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libIlmImf-2_5.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Is 3.2.0 a part of command? Either way I got an error.

Comment: @Asiannoob The "3.2.0" means what the above command should output, note the use of `$` to differentiate commands from output. What version you'd get may be different on your system, though.